# How attach a GCP IAM policy to a resource with gcloud command tool?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I understand GCP IAM roles and policy. However I am struggling to understand how a policy can be **attached** to a finer-grained resource (e.g. GCE instance) with the gcloud tool. I think I've understood that programatically this can be done with REST setIamPolicy() method (e.g. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instances/setIamPolicy). But what about with gcloud command?
I see from here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#updating-gcloud that gcloud command should be

> gcloud [GROUP] add-iam-policy-binding [RESOURCE] --member user:[EMAIL]
>   --role [ROLE_ID]

but I can't find a reference to it. 
thanks.

Comment: Maybe I've just found the answer? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-iam-policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, yes, you're on the right track, but the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-iam-policy) you've linked is for applying a Cloud IAM policy on a GCE instance using a `JSON` or `YAML` file. Alternatively, refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-iam-policy-binding) as to how it's done by specifying the `member` and their `role` directly with `add-iam-policy-binding`.